# Is a sequence of stopping times a(n optional) stochastic process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Assume that $\{S_n\}_{n\in I}$ is a sequence of stopping times, with $I\subset \mathbb{T}$. We can have $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}^+_0$.

Is it possible to see this sequence as an optional stochastic process $S$, where $S:\mathbb{T}\times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Under what conditions?